# Anonymous Authentication in rest wcf

Tags: rest, wcf

All,

I am having WCF Rest service which is working fine with windows authentication but when i am using anonymous authentication it's causing issue, Any help or suggestion much appreciated.

1. App.Config with windows authentication(its working fine) :

````
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm=""/>
              </security>
            </binding> ```

2.  App.Config with anonymous authentication(its causing issue)

``` <binding name="DefaultRestBinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security>
        </binding>```
````

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @ChrisBint   When i am using anonymous authentication as shown below then i am getting error "Bad Request(400)"       <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security>

Comment: Any suggestion or help please.

Comment: We need to enable the Anonymous Authentication in IIS authentication mode. free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: @AbrahamQian           Anonymous Authentication is enabled only in IIS authentication mode. but still same issue.

Comment: Is the Windows authentication enabled in the group ？or the windows authentication doesn’t work.

Comment: Windows authentication is disabled  and when i enable window authentication then it's works fine with windows authentication.

Comment: Sorry, I just notice you use None security, under this issue, https protocol is not available. We should use http service address, or we use Transport security and client credential type to None, then we enable the Anonymous authentication.

Comment: @AbrahamQian..  I did not get you, Would you please explain your above comments in detailed, thanks a lot  for helping me

Comment: Sorry, I have a slip of the tongue, because transportcredential security is already based on http protocol, you can use this security, and then make the clientcredentialType to None, can we solve the problem? Besides, “400 bad request” mainly indicates that the request format is not correct. Do you have tried the GET method? which is easy to test the service.